# SOA admin mail field

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I'm configuring bind name server. But we don't have a mail server in our zone. can I use my gmail as admin mail server? this is the configuration I want to use:

```
mydomain.com.             10800 IN SOA ns1.mydomain.com. mymail.gmail.com. (
                                2016051901 ; serial
                                10800      ; refresh (3 hours)
                                900        ; retry (15 minutes)
                                1814400    ; expire (3 weeks)
                                10800      ; minimum (3 hours)
                                )
```

is it valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

[RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#page-19) only specifies

> A `domain-name` which specifies the mailbox of the
> person responsible for this zone.

It doesn't require the domain name to belong to the same zone.

An example:

```
dig soa serverfault.com

;; ANSWER SECTION:
serverfault.com.    86400   IN  SOA cf-dns01.serverfault.com. dns.cloudflare.com. 2021542560 10000 2400 604800 3600
```

so SF uses dns@cloudflare.com in their SOA.